# Windows 10 start search bar doesn't work when connected to a network with no internet access

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, search

I noticed there are some other questions similar in nature where the search bar fails to work under any circumstance.

However, my search bar works fine when connected to the internet or disconnected from any network. Instead, if I'm connected to a network that has no external internet access the search bar stops working altogether. As soon as I disconnect the Ethernet cable the search bar starts working again.

Is there a solution?